# How to make my function return results as a global variable?

Tags: php, variables

First time poster here...

Just wondering if anyone can help me turn my function's results into a global variable that I can use in another php page...

```
$sql = "SELECT title FROM table_1 WHERE id >= '1' and id <='10'";


    function dbCall($servername, $username, $password, $dbname, $sql) {
        global $item;
            $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
            if ($conn->connect_error) {
                die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            } 

                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                    // output data of each row
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

                       $item=("'". $row[0]."', ");
                       echo $item;
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "0 results";
            }
                    return $list;
                    $conn->close();
            }
```

Currently it returns a list of the results:

```
'tom', 'mary', 'joseph', 'jim', 'kathy', 'bob', 'luke', 'sam', 'heidi', 'tiffany',
```

But I can't call this as a global variable in my other php page...

Could anyone help?

Edit:

Actually when I call the fucntion I get this one the other page:

```
include ("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\db-call.php");
$varList = array(dbCall($servername, $username, $password, $dbname));
echo $varList;
```

And I get this result back:

```
'tom', 'mary', 'joseph', 'jim', 'kathy', 'bob', 'luke', 'sam', 'heidi', 'tiffany',Array
```

Thanks again!---

Thanks,

Comment: How do I use this..??
edit: nvm - i think i found the PHP manual page...

Comment: there are various tutorials, just search. session_start() is the beginning

Comment: Thanks Thamilan, I'll give it a try;.. Could you take a look at my other page to see if thers something I'm doing wrong? Thanks,

Comment: Why the `array` word? `$varList = dbCall($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);` is enough right??

Comment: Its for a function that my colleagues working on..

But it seems like when I try to call $varList..i'd still get the same output..
but the $varList doesn't hold any of the variables..

`$varList=dbCall($servername, $username, $password, $dbname, $sql);
 $List=array($varList);`

I get this return still: 
`'tom', 'mary', 'joseph', 'jim', 'kathy', 'bob', 'luke', 'sam', 'heidi', 'tiffany',Array`

Comment: What are you assigning to `$list`? don't use echo inside function, assign `$list` with those values you printed

Comment: How do I do that??? Haven't I already done that?
`$item=("'". $row[0]."', ");
                       echo $item;`

Comment: Check the answer I added...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your function to return the values, not print the values:

```
function dbCall($servername, $username, $password, $dbname, $sql) {
    $item = [];
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                    // output data of each row
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

            $item[] = $row[0];
        }
    } else {
        $item[] = "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
    return $item;
}
```

Now when you call like this:

```
include ("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\db-call.php");
$varList = dbCall($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
echo $varList;
```

Your `$varList` contains array, you can process with those values as you need

```
Array
(
    [0] => tom
    [1] => mary
    [2] => joseph
    [3] => jim
    [4] => kathy
    [5] => bob
    [6] => luke
    [7] => sam
    [8] => heidi
    [9] => tiffany
)
```

Comment: Thanks Thamil! Is there anyway I can call all the arrays at once as one string?

Comment: Use implode. `echo implode(" ",$varList);` or if you want like the same use `echo "'".implode("', '",$varList)."'";`

Comment: Oh... damn! Thanks Thamilan!

Comment: Thamilan... Is there anyway to return the implode as strictly a variable/string?

Comment: Your expected output?

Comment: Well its the expect output right now; its just my colleagues code doesn't seemt o be reading it despite it being `'tom', 'mary', 'joseph', 'jim', 'kathy', 'bob', 'luke', 'sam', 'heidi', 'tiffany'`...

I'm wondering if its because its reading this return as something different?

Comment: Could it have something to do with the fact tht i'm using this :
`$List = ("'".implode("', '",$varList)."'");

 $List2 =array($List);` ??

Comment: why you want list2 with $list as array? Much confused I think

Comment: nvM! I realized that it was already an array to begin wtih :P

Answer (score 0):

Probably the better way is to include this file in the page you want to use and call the function to get the list.

Comment: `include ("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\db-call.php");
$list = array(dbCall($servername, $username, $password, $dbname, $sql));
echo $list;`

Comment: This is pretty much a small example of the code I'm using, but it doesnt' seem to work..

Comment: based on your code, it seems like no value is assigned to $list in dbCall function, maybe you can try to return $item, instead of return $list ?

Comment: Hey Herris, Where would I add that...? Thanks,